# What is replacement for Vuetify 2 v-date-picker in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a custom component that used `v-date-picker` in Laravel 9 Vue2 & Vuetify 2 applications. I am upgrading it to Laravel 10 Vue3/Vuetify 3. I unable to find a date picker in Vuetify 3 (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/). Is a date picker available in Vuetify3? If not, what do you suggest to use in its place? (I need to control if the user can enter past or future dates).

Comment: I think until Q2 2023 date picker component won't be available for v3 https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#up-next.

Comment: Any suggestion for its replacement via any other vue 3 package. I am looking for a simple date selector (no time selection is required) with option/props to enable/disable future or past dates. I need date output in YYYY-MM-DD format to store it in MySQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version v3.3.4 the date picker component is available:

```
<v-date-picker></v-date-picker>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/

Comment: Can you give more information on how to use it? When I try using it, it shows the warning `Failed to resolve component: v-date-picker`

Comment: Unfortunately, the use of v-date-picker is not straightforward as other components, like v-btn or v-select. First, it requires v3.3.4. You also need to import DayJsAdapter and include it in createVuetify.  See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/ for dtails

Comment: It also isn't an input field, it's the picker itself, you need to handle the input display, menu...etc yourself

Answer (score 9):

You can use `v-text-field` with `type="date"`, which uses the browser's date picker:
`<v-text-field type="date" label="Date"></v-text-field>`

Here's how it's rendered in Chrome and very similar in Edge:
[image: v-text-field with type="date" rendered in Chrome]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Is it difficult to add options like do not allow future or past dates with this date control?

Comment: @user761100 Yes, set `min` and `max` values to set the allowable range.  Set `value` to set the default value.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

`<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2023-05-03" min="2023-01-01" max="2023-12-31">`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package until they have official datePicker in vuetify

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuepic/vue-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

They dont have the official daterangepicker for now.
But they released Datepicker but not the DateRangePicker.You can try this [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not talking about Laravel.
Just as an example, I was able to use v-date-picker in my Nuxt project. v-date-picker is a Labs feature so you may need to import vuetify/labs/VDatePicker.
I am not familiar enough with Laravel to provide a correct answer, but I hope you can solve this!

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-date-picker ></v-date-picker>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { VDatePicker } from 'vuetify/labs/VDatePicker'
</script>
```